# Killing a MySQL query when the page is abandoned or fails from timeout

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

This question is related to [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19403652/2029629)
([MySQL: Huge tables that need to be joined, how should be splitted for optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19403652/2029629)).

The problem is that I have a site in production and database timeouts are currently affecting performance of the site.  While I need a deep solution of the problem I also need a temporal one.  Currently the database queries are taking too long (I had extended web server timeouts from 30 s to 90 s yet it still fails and this affect the next queries, even queries that would execute faster.

I presume that the long query is still running in the background in the MySQL server even if the PHP script has failed by timeout.

Is this pressumption right?

If it is so.  How can I kill the query process automatically when either the page is closed, another page is requested in the browser window or the page timeouts?

My site is running in a LAMP shared host where I have no root privileges.

Comment: "I presume that the long query is still running in the background in the MySQL server even if the PHP script has failed by timeout.

Is this pressumption right?"  Yes that is correct.